# C Program returning a % with answer

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to calculate the length of a string by using a function. I know there is a predefined function but I wanted to make my own one. But the problem here is whenever I am running this code, it returns the length of the name with a %. Like this:

```
~ >>> /home/******/Coding/strlen                                         
Enter your name ==> Example
The length of your name is 7%
```

I am really confused why this is happening. Please figure me out with what is wrong with my code... I am using GCC Version 10.2.0

```
/*String Length Using Function*/
#include <stdio.h>
int find_length(char[]);
int main()
{
    char name[20];
    int l;
    printf("Enter your name ==> ");
    scanf("%s",name);
    l = find_length(name);
    printf("The length of your name is %d",l);
    return 0;   
}
int find_length(char tempname[])
{
    int len=0, i;
    for(i = 0; tempname [i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your shell is adding the `%` to tell you that your program didn't print a newline character at the end of output.

Add newline character to your output to prevent that.

```
    /* add \n to print a newline character */
    printf("The length of your name is %d\n",l);
```

Comment: What shell does this?

Comment: @NateEldredge Only ZSH seems to do this. Dash and Bash seem to start the shell from the end of the printed line...